# php composer update (lavaler generatore)

Tags: composer-php

Ive been having problems running composer update for a lavaler system I have 'iongerited'.

So first I tried funning composer update with the current version of composer (v2) and got

```
$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
The "composer/installers" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laracasts/generators dev-master -> satisfiable by laracasts/generators[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - laracasts/generators dev-master requires illuminate/support ~6.0|~7.0|~8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v4.0.0-BETA2, ..., 4.2.x-dev, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
```

I tried this with v1.1.1 of composer and got

```
$ COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file


  [ErrorException]
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

So I guess I do need v2 so that did not help.

My composer.json is

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "backpack/crud": "^3.6",
        "backpack/permissionmanager": "^4.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "^0.4.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.4",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "backpack/generators": "^1.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "laracasts/generators": "dev-master",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm verry new to Lavael and php composer. PHP version is 7.3.23, ime running on EC2 ubuntu 18.04.5.

Any help greatfully recived.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [package's detail page](https://packagist.org/packages/laracasts/generators), `laracasts/generators` in version `dev-master` is not compatible with Laravel v5. You need to downgrade this package to v1.2.

You should also check for an updated version of Composer. There's no need to jump to v2 with an existing application, but Composer v1.1.1 was released in May 2016 and is horribly outdated.

Comment: OK, very strange.  The whole filesystem is from git and its supposed to have everything from the running live system up to date.  This included composer.json.  So it looks like this is not true (i.e. it cant be running version from live).  Or am i missing something.

Comment: Simply do not use `composer update` unless you know that this updates your dependencies :)

Comment: OK,  "backpack/generators": "^1.2", so is it not already at 1.2?

Comment: I don't get that question - that requirement asks for a version which is at least 1.2, but not yet 2.0. But how does this relate to the question?

Comment: Keep in mind: `laracasts/generators` is a different package than `backpack/generators`